# How to deploy Xamarin ASP.NET MVC (on Mac) project with Apache

Tags: asp.net-mvc, apache, mono

I'm just starting to learn about Apache and web development using C# ASP.NET and Xamarin/Mono. I've created an ASP.NET MVC Project using Xamarin Studio and when I press play, it opens up in 127.0.0.1:8080 and works as expected.

Now I'd like to deploy this little website using Apache. I have installed `mod_mono`, `mono-2.10` and `xsp-2.10` as suggested by the install guide. I have also changed my Apache `httpd.conf` file in the following way:

```
LoadModule mono_module /usr/libexec/apache2/mod_mono.so

Include /etc/apache2/mod_mono.conf
MonoServerPath /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mod-mono-server2
MonoAutoApplication enabled

<Location /mono>
    SetHandler mono-ctrl
    Allow from all
</Location>

MonoApplications "/TestSite/"
<Location /TestSite/>
        SetHandler mono
</Location>
```

My Xamarin Project lives at the `/TestSite/` location, but when I try to go there, I just get `Service Temporarily Unavailable`. What steps am I missing? Is this not the way to deploy a Xamarin Studio MVC solution?

Here is the `TestSite` folder set up, as created by Xamarin Studio:

[image]

There doesn't seem to be much information online, but I'm sure it's possible! I'm just confused, I guess :) 
Thank you!

Comment: The tags `monotouch` or `xamarin` are generally used for the mobile solution.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC depends on ASP.NET 4, and therefore you should not use `mod-mono-server2` but `mod-mono-server4`.

This discussion can give you more info, https://askubuntu.com/questions/202615/asp-net-4-0-on-mod-mono, but essentially it targets Ubuntu, not OS X.